# Javascript: Recursive function not recognizing changes in variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

#### Background:

Thanks ahead of time for any help you can offer. I'm playing around with a home-spun procedurally generated music app to get more familiar with JavaScript (*I know this has done before but I'm blacking other methods out to see if I can develop my own*).

I am currently determining the *`beats/minute`* via a range slider which triggers a function to calculate the correct values for *`1/16`*, *`1/8`*, *`1/4`*, *`1/2`*, and *`1/1`* notes plus a 20-millisecond gap between the playing note and the next.

I have a second recursive function that then randomly chooses an array value which contains the newly calculated note durations in milliseconds and plays the note for the determined duration. My issue is that the new duration values are not dynamically passing into the recursive function (i.e., changing the value of the slider correctly alters the note duration variables, but it has zero effect on the length of the note being played).

#### Question:

Am I passing something incorrectly? Is there something obvious I've missed? Thanks again for any insight you might have.

#### Code:

```
<!-- BPM Slider -->
<input type="range" min="80" max="180" value="120" step="1" oninput="getBPM(this.value)" onchange="getBPM(this.value)">
</br>
<p id="bpm">120</p>
</br>

<!--- PLAY BUTTON -->
<button type="button" id="toggle" onclick="buttonFunc(), leadOneFunc()">PLAY</button>

<script>

var button = false;
var LeadOneLength = 333;
var quNote = (60000 / 120) - 20;
var eiNote = (60000 / (120 * 2)) - 20;
var siNote = (60000 / (120 * 4)) - 20;
var haNote = (60000 / (120 / 2)) - 20;
var whNote = (60000 / (120 / 4)) - 20;
var noteDur = [siNote, eiNote, quNote, haNote, whNote];
var lead1 = new Audio('tone1.ogg');

/* GET NOTE DURATIONS BSED ON BPM SLIDER INPUT */
function getBPM(bpmVal) {
    document.getElementById("bpm").innerHTML = Number(bpmVal);
    quNote = (60000 / Number(bpmVal)) - 20;
    eiNote = (60000 / (Number(bpmVal) * 2)) - 20;
    siNote = (60000 / (Number(bpmVal) * 4)) - 20;
    haNote = (60000 / (Number(bpmVal) / 2)) - 20;
    whNote = (60000 / (Number(bpmVal) / 2)) - 20;
    bpmVal = Number(bpmVal);
}

/* LEAD INSTRUMENT RNG AND PLAY FUNCTION */
function leadOneFunc() {
    /* RANDOMIZES DURATION OF SINGLE NOTE BASED ON TEMPO */
    var leadOneDur = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    leadOneLength = noteDur[leadOneDur];
    console.log(noteDur[leadOneDur]);
    console.log(quNote);
    lead1.pause();
    /* IF TOGGLE IS SET TO PLAY, WILL PLAY NOTE FOR GENERATED DURATION AND PITCH AND RECURSE THROUGH FUNCTION RE-RANDOMIZING THE NEXT NOTE */
    if(button === true) {
    setTimeout(function() {lead1.currentTime = 0; lead1.play();}, 20);
    setTimeout(leadOneFunc, leadOneLength);
    }
    /* IF TOGGLE IS SET TO STOP, WILL PAUSE ALL AUDIO */
    else {
    lead1.pause();
    }
}

/* TOGGLE BUTTON VARIABLE DEFINITION & BUTTON DISPLAY CHANGE*/
function buttonFunc() {
    if(button === false) {
    button = true; 
    document.getElementById('toggle').innerHTML = 'STOP';
    }
    else {
    button = false; document.getElementById('toggle').innerHTML = 'PLAY';
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the function *getBPM* is not changing the array *noteDur* at all. It sets global variables like *quNote*, but changing those will have no effect on *noteDur*. Instead you should really repopulate your *noteDur* array.

With some additional improvements, you could use this function:

```
function getNoteDurations(bpm) {
    arr = [];
    for (var factor = 4; factor >= 0.25; factor /= 2) {
        arr.push((60000 / (bpm * factor)) - 20);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

And use it as follows in your main script:

```
var noteDur = getNoteDurations(120);
```

And call it in *getBPM*:

```
function getBPM(bpmVal) {
    document.getElementById("bpm").textContent = bpmVal;
    noteDur = getNoteDurations(+bpmVal);
}
```

Comment: This is great. I knew it had to be something that I was fundamentally missing. Repopulating the duration array was absolutely the key. Thanks for your input.